# Blazor Navigation Back Casue page to re render

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor, I have a page shows a list of products I scroll down to s specific product and click it and go to product details, but when the user return back by browser back  the product list page is re rendered and so the user see the product list from the first Item and loose where he was, and also it refreshes the list so it me need some time to render, is there any way to prevent this and make it normal back Navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the [lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0) methods that you have to the page. What is probably happening is every time you navigate to a product list page (a component) it loads the product list for the first time. Then when you click on the product list, you navigate to another page.

To get the experience you want you'll want to somehow save the scroll position of on the Product List page. OR you could just use a modal to surface the product Or another way to show the Product Details without navigating out of the Product List page.

Comment: thank you for your answer , as I found after a long search this is the nature of Blazor (reloading the page ) so we have to work around this. save the scroll position is not possible in my case because I am using endless scrolling and using modal is a good idea but in this case I will lose the product page for google indexing, I think putting a small unclickable link will solve the issue and will make the ability to show the product page separately if it is shared through social media